# AWS EC2 connects to RDS inside VPC without passing throught Internet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

In AWS VPC I have an RDS instance with endpoint xxxname.xxxcode.eu-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com.

If an EC2 instance in a public subnet in the same VPC connects to that RDS instance, is traffic going throught Internet or staying inside AWS network?
Being the RDS instance publicly accessible is relevant to that?

Do I need an Interface VPC endpoint to route traffic to RDS instance without going throught Internet?

If yes, being the Interface VPC endpoint something like vpce-xxxcode.rds.eu-south-1.vpce.amazonaws.com, what will be the endpoint to my RDS instance to privately connect?

Comment: If publicly accessible is set to true then it will resolve the hostname over the internet. If you dont want that behavior set it to false.

Comment: @Kisaragi I'm not sure that's true. I think the VPC's internal DNS resolver would resolve it to the private IP of the RDS server. It would be easy to test that from an SSH console on the EC2 instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the RDS instance is in the same VPC, the endpoint name will resolve to an IP address internal to the VPC. When your EC2 instance connects to the RDS, it will use the VPC DNS resolver and will use the resolved private address. The connection will not be made over the public Internet.

Comment: Thanks for answer. So if the RDS and EC2 instances are in the same VPC, then the RDS endpoint would be resolved to RDS private IP address, even if the subnet is public and if RDS is publicly accessible, right?

Comment: Yes. You can confirm this by connecting to the EC2 instance and using `dig <endpoint>`. It should resolve to a private address within the CIDR range of your VPC.

Comment: So what is the role of Interface VPC Endpoint for RDS service? Is it used only to request API operations and to access RDS instances from different VPC?

Comment: Only for RDS API operations. To connect to the database hosted on an RDS instance (e.g. a MySQL or Postgresql connection) in another VPC, you'd typically use VPC peering or a VPN connection, as outlined here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.Scenarios.html.

Comment: Thanks again. Does the said above resolution to RDS private IP requires that both VPC attributes 'enableDnsSupport' and 'enableDnsHostnames' are set to True, or this requirement only interests the Interface VPC Endpoint resolution?

Comment: Yes, this answer assumes that both of those settings are True (the default setting).